# Stuck here on prime number

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code of mine, i am not sure what's wrong.
for eg: this seems proper to calculate prime
but when I tried for number 99 it shows it is a prime no.

```
num=int(input('Enter a positive no.\n'))
prime=False
if num==1:
    prime=False
elif num==2:
    prime=True
else:
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num%2==0:
            prime=False
        else:
            prime=True

if prime:
    print('Prime no.')
else:
    print('Not a prime')
```

Comment: The logic is incorrect but at exactly which part??

Comment: Think about number `9`? What is the definition of a prime number? What if 3 or 5 or 7 multipliers??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Use backticks `\`\`\`` for code blocks. Not single quotes `'''`.

Comment: `if num%2==0:` checks if the number is even.

Comment: Also, since you don't `break` out of the loop, the entire loop is basically nullified and you are just testing in `num - 1` is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing:

```
if num%2==0:
    prime=False
```

This makes you check if the number is even or not as you are checking for divisibility only by 2. What you should do is:

```
if num%i==0:
    prime=False
    break
```

That way, you would be checking if there are any other factors of the number. Also, the break statement breaks you out of the loop immediately after spotting a factor. That way, in the case of 99, the loop immediately stops after the logic sees that 9 is a factor and hence 99 is not a prime. Otherwise the loop runs till 98 and as it sees 99%98 is not zero, it overwrites the flag value and you still see that 99 is a prime.

P.S: For the purpose of making your code faster, you might also want to put `range(2,(num/2)+1)` instead of `range(2,num)`